# Freeze header on export to excel from SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, excel, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have the header in my report on SSRS frozen so it scrolls down as I scroll down the page. Is it possible to keep this header frozen when I export the report to excel so it will do the same in excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do so with table headings. However, items that appear in the Page Header section of a report do get exported to frozen heading rows in Excel.

Comment: In my experience the only thing SSRS Excel export uses Freeze Panes for is for the PageHeader and only when SimpleHeaders=false (the default). Excel export ignores the FixedHeaders property.

Comment: See here for simpleheaders=true: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/4f5b0154-b5b4-4789-8ac9-06fb53370d85/